Publish to AUR from non-Arch System
Just migrated from Arch to Fedora. Got some apps I've been publishing to the AUR.
Is it possible to update those AUR repos without having Arch, directly from Fedora?
Or am I better to setup an Arch-based system in a VM just to publish for that platform?
The issue is that updpkgsums and makepkg are unavailable.

It should be theoretically possible, but since this is very unusual, building (und updating) all the tools (and toolchain dependencies) would be a neverending nightmare on non-arch.
I would setup a Arch based VM for this. This will save you a lot of headaches.
